# Play MIDI from DAW with Korg Volca FM

Tags: midi, synthesizer, daw, audio-interfaces, logic

I want to be able to play MIDI notes written in my DAW via my Korg Volca FM.

I checked several articles and the general idea consists of these steps:

- create MIDI track in DAW
- DAW track sends MIDI data to Korg Volca FM
- Volca sends audio into Audio Interface
- track's DAW audio input comes from audio interface

Keeping this idea in mind I ended with the following setup with the help of devices that I have:

- I have MIDI track with notes in DAW (Logic Pro X)
- DAW's i/o is connected to Audio Interface (Xeryx302usb) via usb
- Arturia Keystep controller is connected to DAW as slave via usb
- Controller's MIDI-out is connected to Korg Volca FM MIDI-in
- Volca audio out is connected into Audio Interface's stereo line

[image]

I'm able to play controller's keys and hear volca's sound. Also when I hit play in DAW, controller and volca sequencers are enabled which is fine cause they are slaves. But unfortunately notes written in track are not played. I assume that controller is not passing this data from DAW into Volca... do you have any ideas?

Comment: **set MIDI-thru to "ON" in Keystep software settings solved this issue!**